# alternate running timer jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a timer that when idle is running talk is pause and vice versa and when I click idle, idle will resume its counting and vice versa

```js
var count_idle = $('#ctr_idle').text();
var count_talk = $('#ctr_talk').text();

function clock_idle() {
  count_idle++;
  $('#ctr_idle').text(count_idle);
}

function clock_talk() {
  count_talk++;
  $('#ctr_talk').html(count_talk);
}

$('#status').change(function() {
  var choice = $('#status').val();
  console.log(choice);

  if (choice == 'talk') {
    clearInterval(timer_idle);
    var timer_talk = setInterval(clock_talk, 1000);

  } else {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
    var timer_idle = setInterval(clock_idle, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>TIMER
    <select id = "status">
      <option value="idle">Idle</option>
      <option value="talk">Talk_time</option>
    </select>
  </h1>
  <h3>Idle: <span id="ctr_idle"></span></h3>
  <h3>Talk_time: <span id="ctr_talk"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you're trying to do as your question is not clear at all. You also haven't asked a question, nor given details of what the problem is.

Comment: I want to make a timer that when idle is running , the talk is pause and when the talk is selected the idle count is will pause, and when I go back to idle the count of idle will resume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

`var timer_talk ;    var timer_idle;` added with in `global` variable .
Clear Interval is not working. Because the variable are private not a global

```js
var count_idle = $('#ctr_idle').text();
var count_talk = $('#ctr_talk').text();
var timer_talk ;//global
var timer_idle;//global
function clock_idle() {
  count_idle++;
  $('#ctr_idle').text(count_idle);
}

function clock_talk() {
  count_talk++;
  $('#ctr_talk').html(count_talk);
}

$('#status').change(function() {
  var choice = $('#status').val();
  console.log(choice);

  if (choice == 'talk') {
    clearInterval(timer_idle);
    timer_talk = setInterval(clock_talk, 1000);

  } else {
    clearInterval(timer_talk);
     timer_idle = setInterval(clock_idle, 1000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <h1>TIMER
    <select id = "status">
      <option value="idle">Idle</option>
      <option value="talk">Talk_time</option>
    </select>
  </h1>
  <h3>Idle: <span id="ctr_idle"></span></h3>
  <h3>Talk_time: <span id="ctr_talk"></span></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome.Glad to help you..!